# 2D Laplace Equation in Polar Coordinates on Half-Disk with Neumann Conditions

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions

Assume the 2D Laplace Equation $$\nabla^2 u =0 $$ in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$. The general solution is 
$$u(r,\theta) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}r^n[A_n\cos(n\theta) + B_n\sin(n\theta)].$$
Now assume Neumann boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(r,\pm\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(1,\theta) = u(1,\theta) - 1.$$

Does a non-trivial solution exist? If yes, then what is the solution?

Comment: Update: A small typo in my question: the second Neumann condition should be $\partial u / \partial r (1,\theta) = u(1, \theta) - 1$, a partial derivative to r. Assume also the domain r = 0..1 and $\theta = -pi/2..pi/2$ only.